# CSS center multiline text but with shortest line on top?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have some html, css similar to this:

```
<div style="width: 40em; text-align: center;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex
</div>
```

which renders like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cubetr3c1hbrfkp/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-05%20at%2023.58.10%20.png) but i want that the shortest line to be on top, like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfomexmm52avk63/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-05%20at%2023.59.53%20.png).
i am unable to figure out how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is automatically displayed by web browser until the end of the block width. If you want something diferent you must use a break.

```
<div style="width: 40em; text-align: center;">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
    of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
    industry's standard dummy tex
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that would not work when the windows is to small "width: 100%" and more text. Here is an example: http://bartel.ws/ resize the window and watch the icons at the bottom.